# TypeScript Date type is not JS Date type?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a model:

```
export class SendModel{
periodFrom: Date,
periodTo: Date
}
```

I have a service:

```
public async Calculate(periodFrom: Date,  periodTo: Date):Promise<SendModel>
{
let resObj = this.http.get(url, params:{periodFrom: `${periodFrom}`, periodTo: `${periodTo}`}).toPromise();
//...another code...//
}
```

I receive a SendModel object from api.

```
{
periodFrom: '2022-11-24T00-00-00Z',
periodTo: '2026-01-01T00-00-00Z'
}
```

Ok, I need add 3 month to periodFrom var.

```
let startPayday = receiveObj.periodFrom.setMonth(receiveObj.periodFrom.getMonth()+3); //not working, despite receiveObj.periodFrom has type is Date (what?)
let startPayday2 = new Date(new Date(receiveObj.periodFrom).setMonth(new Date(receiveObj.periodFrom).getMonth()+3)); //worsk! ok
```

Ok, let`s send it to api.

```
this.service.Calculate(startPayday2, receiveObj.periodTo); //error!
```

Wrong api call, status 400, One or more validation errors.
Look at the request: `api/calculate?periodFrom=Fri Feb 24 2023 03:00:00 GMT 0300 (blablabla)&periodTo=2026-01-01T00-00-00Z`

Maybe like this?

```
this.service.Calculate(startPayday2.toISOString(), receiveObj.periodTo); //nope, argument is type 'string' bla-bal-bla...
```

startPayday2 has type Date, API expects type Date, but these are different types that are serialized differently?

Comment: Those things in your response object are strings, not Date instances. JSON does not have a way of encoding Date instances. You have to make those yourself from the strings.

Comment: You'll have to format your Date strings to go back to the server in a form it expects, which is probably the ISO standard that you're getting (with the "T" in the middle).

Comment: this.service.Calculate expects type Date, not a string

Comment: Fine, but if you're sending stuff over HTTP you cannot send a Date instance. If it's a local service, then converting to an ISO string is clearly wrong if it really expects a Date instance.

Comment: And the direct answer to the question in the title is that they are the same. Typescript is compiled to JavaScript somewhere along the line before anything actually happens in the browser (or in Node, or whatever).